# Query for Linking Purchase Orders with Sales Orders

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I'm writing a report that includes sales order info + delivery notes. What I'm trying to do is add information from the purchase orders (ex. PO # & Price) table (I believe it is OPOR). How do I link this table to one or more of the tables I already have? Please see my query below:

```
SELECT o0.NumAtCard AS OrderNo 
,i0.DocNum 
,i0.TrackNo AS TrackingNo
,i0.CardName
, o0.DocNum AS DelivDoc 
FROM ODLN d0 
INNER JOIN DLN1 d1 ON d0.DocEntry = d1.DocEntry 
LEFT OUTER JOIN INV1 i1 ON d1.TrgetEntry = i1.DocEntry 
LEFT OUTER JOIN OINV i0 ON i1.DocEntry = i0.DocEntry 
INNER JOIN ORDR o0 ON d1.BaseEntry = o0.DocEntry
INNER JOIN OITM itm ON i1.ItemCode = itm.ItemCode 
WHERE o0.CANCELED = 'N' AND 
i0.TrackNo IS NOT NULL 
GROUP BY o0.NumAtCard 
|,i0.DocNum 
|,i0.TrackNo 
,i0.CardName 
,o0.DocNum 
ORDER BY o0.NumAtCard
```

Comment: What sort f information do you want in the table?  And how does it join in?

Comment: I'd like to add purchase order no & price to the report

Comment: In place or in addition to the ORDR table?  If in addition, if you have 4 ORDR entries and three purchase orders how many rows do you expect out?  12?

Comment: The purchase orders are linked to the sales orders. Purchase orders are for goods bought by our company, which we then sell to our customers. So my 4 ORDR entries should be linked to 4 other purchase orders.

Comment: What is your primary/foreign key relationship there?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so on the back and forth, it is clear the real question is about how to go about adding the information to the query.

A SQL consists of several major pieces in order:

1. The column list
2. The table/join specification (FROM and JOIN clauses)
3. The where section (WHERE...)
4. Aggregate rules (GROUP BY/Having)
5. Limit and offset (LIMIT/OFFSET)

In your case you need to start by identifying the information in the database you want to add, and how it relates to what you have already.  So in this case you are going to:

1. Add the columns as necessary to the column list (the part between `SELECT` and `FROM`)
2. Add the  table to the join list (via a `LEFT JOIN`, with the join condition following `ON`).  So if you have a so_docnum field that matches the sales order docnum field it would be something like `LEFT OUTER JOIN OPOR po ON po.so_docnum = o0.docnum`)
3. Add anything needed to the `GROUP BY` clause (probably the fields you are adding from the PO).

However, your first step is to map out the data so that these steps can be executed because it is clear you don't have all the information you need to add it yet.

Comment: But is it clear? This answer is not useful because it offers insultingly low level of advice to someone who is clearly intermediate or better. When we ask calculus question don't come back at us with explanations of differences between addition and division, because it is rude. The guy is asking about which fields to link with, which are dependent on his local SAP B1 system configuration to be honest, but you can search for information on SO to PO linking tables related to RDR1.LinePoPrss at https://launchpad.support.sap.com please and thank you ;]